# Need Help Animating Images in an HBox using JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, javafx-8

I'm working on creating a simulation program for a game called Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, and I'm stuck on how I should animate certain images within an HBox. In the game, there are Weapon Cases containing various skins of different rarity. Upon clicking the 'Open' button, the possible items to win should start scrolling through the HBox. Think of it almost like Wheel of Fortune, where it begins fast and gradually slows down until it stops on 1 name, but in this case, instead of names there are items, and instead of a 'wheel', I have a horizontal HBox with images scrolling through. Here is a good example of what I'm trying to make: http://cases.goaggro.com/.

Currently, I have an instance of the ImageView class assigned to each individual weapon image that should be included in the total group of items to be rolled, and an array to hold all of these images. On the GUI, I have the HBox's max width and height set so that any 3 of these images placed inside the HBox from left to right fill its' volume perfectly. My first problem resides here. If I try to do something like

```
Hbox.getChildren().addAll(itemArray);
```

it will add the first 3 just fine, but will continue to add images beyond the boundaries of the HBox until reaching the main windows border. Is there any way to add more images into the HBox than the max displayed image count (being 3 due to the current HBox size I have set) while preventing them from exceeding the HBox boundaries and simply being hidden in the back?

The second question is, what would be the best way to go about animating each image inside of my HBox so that it scrolls towards the left but not beyond or outside of the HBox borders? I need the left-most image to slide left off the screen, while the middle image slides to the left position, and a new image slides in from the right to fill the right position, and repeat this at a speed that gradually slows to the point of landing on an item.

Currently, adding this code to the 'Open' button's event handler adds the images in item1, item2, and item3 correctly into the HBox. But if I exceed 3 images (like setting the HBox .addAll() to itemArray instead of the first 3 items individually, for example), it exceeds the HBox border and starts laying them on top of the scene until reaching the main windows border. **NOTE:** There are a total of 15 instances of the ImageView class (item1-item15) but I shortened the code to only 4, as well as the arrays contents to those 4, since the issue happens regardless when any more than 3 images are placed into the HBox.

```
public class Controller
{
@FXML
private HBox hBox;

    public void openCaseAction(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {
            final ImageView item1 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/image1.png")));
            final ImageView item2 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/image2.png")));
            final ImageView item3 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/image3.png")));
            final ImageView item4 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/image4.png")));

            final ImageView[] itemArray ={item1,item2,item3,item4};

            hBox.getChildren().addAll(item1,item2,item3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a custom layout for this rather than a HBox.  Take a look at the Display Shelf example:

1. Download the [Java 8 demos and samples from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
2. Extract the sample package.
3. Run the demo/javafx_samples/Ensemble8.jar program.
4. Type "Display Shelf" into the program's search bar.
5. View the Display Shelf example UI and source code.
6. Copy and modify as you see fit while respecting the original license terms.

It won't be exactly what you are looking for but it will be a much closer starting point than trying to animate items in a HBox.

[image: display shelf]

Oracle DisplayShelf sample code:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
package ensemble.samples.graphics2d.displayshelf;

import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Simple 7 segment LED style digit. It supports the numbers 0 through 9.
 */
/**
 * A ui control which displays a browse-able display shelf of images
 */
public class DisplayShelf extends Region {

    private final Duration DURATION = Duration.millis(500);
    private final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = Interpolator.EASE_BOTH;
    private final double SPACING = 50;
    private final double LEFT_OFFSET = -110;
    private final double RIGHT_OFFSET = 110;
    private final double SCALE_SMALL = 0.7;
    private PerspectiveImage[] items;
    private Group centered = new Group();
    private Group left = new Group();
    private Group center = new Group();
    private Group right = new Group();
    private int centerIndex = 0;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    private boolean localChange = false;
    private Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();

    public DisplayShelf(Image[] images) {
        // set clip
        setClip(clip);
        // set ids for styling via CSS
        setId("displayshelf");  
        scrollBar.setId("display-scrollbar");
        // create items
        items = new PerspectiveImage[images.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            final PerspectiveImage item =
                    items[i] = new PerspectiveImage(images[i]);
            final double index = i;
            item.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) -> {
                localChange = true;
                scrollBar.setValue(index);
                localChange = false;
                shiftToCenter(item);
            });
        }
        // setup scroll bar
        scrollBar.setMax(items.length - 1);
        scrollBar.setVisibleAmount(1);
        scrollBar.setUnitIncrement(1);
        scrollBar.setBlockIncrement(1);
        scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((Observable ov) -> {
            if (!localChange) {
                shiftToCenter(items[(int) Math.round(scrollBar.getValue())]);
            }
        });
        // create content
        centered.getChildren().addAll(left, right, center);
        getChildren().addAll(centered, scrollBar);
        // listen for keyboard events
        setFocusTraversable(true);
        setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                shift(1);
                localChange = true;
                scrollBar.setValue(centerIndex);
                localChange = false;
            } else if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                shift(-1);
                localChange = true;
                scrollBar.setValue(centerIndex);
                localChange = false;
            }
        });
        // update
        update();
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        // update clip to our size
        clip.setWidth(getWidth());
        clip.setHeight(getHeight());
        // keep centered centered
        centered.setLayoutY((getHeight() - PerspectiveImage.HEIGHT) / 2);
        centered.setLayoutX((getWidth() - PerspectiveImage.WIDTH) / 2);
        // position scroll bar at bottom
        scrollBar.setLayoutX(10);
        scrollBar.setLayoutY(getHeight() - 25);
        scrollBar.resize(getWidth() - 20, 15);
    }

    private void update() {
        // move items to new homes in groups
        left.getChildren().clear();
        center.getChildren().clear();
        right.getChildren().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < centerIndex; i++) {
            left.getChildren().add(items[i]);
        }
        center.getChildren().add(items[centerIndex]);
        for (int i = items.length - 1; i > centerIndex; i--) {
            right.getChildren().add(items[i]);
        }
        // stop old timeline if there is one running
        if (timeline != null) {
            timeline.stop();
        }
        // create timeline to animate to new positions
        timeline = new Timeline();
        // add keyframes for left items
        final ObservableList<KeyFrame> keyFrames = timeline.getKeyFrames();
        for (int i = 0; i < left.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            final PerspectiveImage it = items[i];
            double newX = -left.getChildren().size()
                    * SPACING + SPACING * i + LEFT_OFFSET;
            keyFrames.add(new KeyFrame(DURATION,
                    new KeyValue(it.translateXProperty(), newX, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.scaleXProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.scaleYProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.angle, 45.0, INTERPOLATOR)));
        }
        // add keyframe for center item
        final PerspectiveImage centerItem = items[centerIndex];
        keyFrames.add(new KeyFrame(DURATION,
                new KeyValue(centerItem.translateXProperty(), 0, INTERPOLATOR),
                new KeyValue(centerItem.scaleXProperty(), 1.0, INTERPOLATOR),
                new KeyValue(centerItem.scaleYProperty(), 1.0, INTERPOLATOR),
                new KeyValue(centerItem.angle, 90.0, INTERPOLATOR)));
        // add keyframes for right items
        for (int i = 0; i < right.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            final PerspectiveImage it = items[items.length - i - 1];
            final double newX = right.getChildren().size()
                    * SPACING - SPACING * i + RIGHT_OFFSET;
            keyFrames.add(new KeyFrame(DURATION,
                    new KeyValue(it.translateXProperty(), newX, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.scaleXProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.scaleYProperty(), SCALE_SMALL, INTERPOLATOR),
                    new KeyValue(it.angle, 135.0, INTERPOLATOR)));
        }
        // play animation
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void shiftToCenter(PerspectiveImage item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < left.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            if (left.getChildren().get(i) == item) {
                int shiftAmount = left.getChildren().size() - i;
                shift(shiftAmount);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (center.getChildren().get(0) == item) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < right.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            if (right.getChildren().get(i) == item) {
                int shiftAmount = -(right.getChildren().size() - i);
                shift(shiftAmount);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void shift(int shiftAmount) {
        if (centerIndex <= 0 && shiftAmount > 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (centerIndex >= items.length - 1 && shiftAmount < 0) {
            return;
        }
        centerIndex -= shiftAmount;
        update();
    }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
package ensemble.samples.graphics2d.displayshelf;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.effect.PerspectiveTransform;
import javafx.scene.effect.Reflection;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 * A Node that displays a image with some 2.5D perspective rotation around the Y
 * axis.
 */
public class PerspectiveImage extends Parent {

    private static final double REFLECTION_SIZE = 0.25;

    public static final double WIDTH = 200;
    public static final double HEIGHT = WIDTH + (WIDTH * REFLECTION_SIZE);

    private static final double RADIUS_H = WIDTH / 2;
    private static final double BACK = WIDTH / 10;
    private PerspectiveTransform transform = new PerspectiveTransform();
    /**
     * Angle Property
     */
    public final DoubleProperty angle = new SimpleDoubleProperty(45) {
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            // when angle changes calculate new transform
            double lx = (RADIUS_H - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle.get())) * RADIUS_H - 1);
            double rx = (RADIUS_H + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle.get())) * RADIUS_H + 1);
            double uly = (-Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle.get())) * BACK);
            double ury = -uly;
            transform.setUlx(lx);
            transform.setUly(uly);
            transform.setUrx(rx);
            transform.setUry(ury);
            transform.setLrx(rx);
            transform.setLry(HEIGHT + uly);
            transform.setLlx(lx);
            transform.setLly(HEIGHT + ury);
        }
    };

    public final double getAngle() {
        return angle.getValue();
    }

    public final void setAngle(double value) {
        angle.setValue(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty angleModel() {
        return angle;
    }

    public PerspectiveImage(Image image) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        Reflection reflection = new Reflection();
        reflection.setFraction(REFLECTION_SIZE);
        imageView.setEffect(reflection);
        setEffect(transform);
        getChildren().addAll(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This will be very useful. I wasn't even aware that something like a DisplayShelf existed until now, because I've been using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 to create the GUI. So unless I'm seriously missing something, I haven't seen DisplayShelf anywhere in Scene Builder haha. After looking at it though, it may work perfectly if I am able to set it up without a scroll bar, and change its properties so that it doesn't zoom in on each image as they center themselves but rather show them all from the same distance.